# JSON from PHP file returns garbage

Tags: java, php, android, json

I'm trying to get a JSON file from my site example.net/index.php, however I always get some kind of HTML in an Android app rather than JSON object.

Returned string:

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("674bdf26f9a5fe3df1461aafc3120641");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://example.net/index.php?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

Called url:

```
<?php
  $results = array(
      "result"   => "success",
      "username" => "some username",
      "projects" => "some other value"
  );
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Code:

```
public String getJSON(String url, int timeout) {
        HttpURLConnection c = null;
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
            c.setUseCaches(false);
            c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
            c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
            c.connect();
            int status = c.getResponseCode();

            switch (status) {
                case 200:
                case 201:
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line+"\n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                    return sb.toString();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                try {
                    c.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

How do I get the JSON file instead of this HTML code?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the content type,

```
        c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        c.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        c.setUseCaches(false);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but it still returns the same rather than JSON.

Comment: No, but I tried [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/) library and got the same.

Comment: Please try with postman application to make sure the response has JSON format or not or update question with the result. Also, try to use retrofit lib for API calls in android.

Answer (score 0):

Well look at what the html source is trying to tell you:

> This site requires Javascript to work,

You should first use a javascript interpreter on that page to obtain json.

So wrong url. It does not give you json.

If you request that page with a browser the browser will invoke the javascript interpreter without you knowing it.